# MySQL: Composite Index on Where + Order By

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a simple query that is making use of a `where` clause sorted by another column.

```sql
select * 
from `Domains` 
where `status` != 'error_name_not_resolved' 
order by `analyzed_at` asc limit 10;
```

I have three indices:

- One for the `status` column.
- One for the `analyzed_at` column.
- One composite index for the columns `status` and `analyzed_at`.

[image]

Still, the query is really slow and I don't get the answer even after 5 minutes (the table includes 14 million documents).

**What is strange is that the same query in descending order is really fast (response returned in ms).**

```sql
select * 
from `Domains` 
where `status` != 'error_name_not_resolved' 
order by `analyzed_at` desc limit 10;
```

I can also see that the composite index is not the one used with `EXPLAIN`.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: It is possible that the composite index by `(analyzed_at, status)` may help... but the probability is not high. If not than none index may help.

Comment: What is approx. percent of rows which have `status = 'error_name_not_resolved'`?

Comment: @Akina, around 1% to 2%, also what is a none index? (can't find the answer on Google)

Comment: @Akina I think the index that may help is actually the one you mention, but with the swapped columns.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information.  Specifically, a table definition and EXPLAIN output. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: "If not than none index may help" --> "No index is likely to help."

Comment: *around 1% to 2%* This means that 98% of rows matches the condition. In this case the index usage will **decrease** the query performance while comparing with direct table scan. Index usage increases the performance when the amount of rows selected according the conditions is not more than 5-7% of total rows amount.

Answer (score 1):

> One composite index for the columns status and analyzed_at.

If I read the image correctly, you do not have *that* index.  Instead you have the columns in the `INDEX` in the opposite order.

Usually, the "range" test should be last in an `INDEX`, not first.

However, with `status !=` is also a "range", so you are stuck with no way to optimize the query.

Maybe...

Since there are few rows with that `status` value, this kludge may be adequate:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            FROM `Domains` 
            ORDER BY `analyzed_at` ASC
            LIMIT 20  -- note: bigger than desired
         ) AS x
    WHERE `status` != 'error_name_not_resolved' 
    ORDER BY `analyzed_at` ASC
    LIMIT 10  -- note: the desired number
```

Explanation:

- The 'derived' table finds the 20 oldest rows (using the index, below).
- The outer query sees only 20 rows and filters out any with the wrong status.  Caveat:  *It is hoping to still have at least 10 rows*.
- Finally it sorts the 20 rows and limits to the 10 you wanted.  (The ordering from the inner query cannot be assumed to be maintained.)
- The outer query will *not* use any index.  However, with only 20 rows, performance is not a problem.

This formulation would require `INDEX(analyzed_at)` or any index *starting* with `analyzed_at`.  (As you apparently have.)

20 is a lot better than 14,000,000 !